Why is $u\in H^1$ enough s.t. $\int \nabla u\cdot\nabla v$ is a well defined expression?
Definitions
Consider a distribution $T\in \mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$, then we define the distributional derivative by "duality" (Adjoint operator etc.), meaning:
$$T'(\phi):=-T(\phi')\ \ \forall\phi\in\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$$
For a function $u\in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$ one can define a distribution by setting
$$T_u(\phi):=\int_\Omega u\phi dx$$
For these objects we can define the (slightly stronger) weak derivative. If there exists a function $g\in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$ s.t.
$$\int_\Omega u \nabla \phi dx = -\int_\Omega g\phi dx \ \ \forall \phi\in \mathcal{D}(\Omega)$$
then we call $g$ the weak derivative of $u$ (or of $T_u$ i guess? Sometimes people do not distinguish between $u$ and $T_u$...) and say
$$"\nabla u = g\ \text{in the sense of distributions}"$$
So this weak derivative is also a distributional derivative, as far as I understand.
We define the Sobolev space $H^1(\Omega)$ as the set of all functions $u\in L^2(\Omega)$ that have a square integrable weak derivative $g\in L^2(\Omega)$, i.e. $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ if
$$u \in L^2(\Omega) \text{ and } \exists g\in L^2(\Omega): \int_\Omega u\nabla \phi dx=-\int_\Omega g\phi dx \ \ \forall \phi\in \mathcal{D}(\Omega)
$$
When studying the weak poisson problem to find a function $u$ (with $0$-trace on $\partial\Omega)$ that satisfies
$$\int_\Omega\nabla u\cdot\nabla \phi = \int_\Omega f\phi \ \ \forall \phi \in \mathcal{D}(\Omega),$$
people say that $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ ($H^1$ with zero trace) is enough such that this expression is well defined.
But why is this a well defined mathematical expression?
Do we make sense of it by realising, there exists $g\in L^2$, s.t. $\int g\cdot \nabla \phi$ is a well defined expression and therefore
$$\begin{align*}
\int g\cdot \nabla \phi &=(-1)\int u \Delta \phi &&\quad \text{as }\nabla\phi\in\mathcal{D}\text{ and by def. of } g\\
&= \int \nabla u \cdot \nabla \phi &&\quad \text{as }u\in L^2
\end{align*}$$
the last integral is also well-defined?
I am confused, I feel like I understand all prerequisites, but I can't find a reference, where this argument is being made.

If the reason why the question is not being answered is because it is not clear or does not satisfy the forum rules, please let me know.

I can not understand what exact your question is. In fact, $H^{1}$ weak solution is suitable for Hilbert space. You see, $\int\nabla u\cdot\nabla\varphi$, this formula is symmetry bilinear form of $u$ and $\varphi$. So the lax milgram theorem can get existence. As for other type of weak solutions, such as solutions in $W^{m,p}$, there also exists relatively theorem accordinger to Calderon-Zygmund theory. The $H^{1}$ weak solution is the most easy one!

My confusion is why $u\in H^1$ is enough for $\int \nabla u\cdot \nabla \phi$ to be a well defined expression. Is it because we define this integral to be equal to $-\int u \nabla\cdot (\nabla \phi)$ for all $\nabla \phi$? If not, then looking at $\int \nabla u\cdot \nabla \phi$ means that $u$ has to be at least $C^1$ so that $\nabla u$ makes sense, correct?

$u\in H^{1}$ can make sense, don't need $u\in C^{1}$

yes but why does it make sense?

By Cauchy-Schwarz we have $$\int \vert \nabla u \vert \vert \nabla v \vert \leq \left(\int \vert \nabla u\vert^2\right)^{1/2} \left( \int \vert \nabla v \vert^2\right)^{1/2} <\infty$$ as the weak derivatives are in $L^2$ by assumption.

But what is "$\nabla u$"? The weak derivative of $u$ is $\nabla T_u(\phi)$ defined as $-\int u\nabla\phi=\int g\phi$. Is $L^2\ni \nabla u = g$?

I think you should see the definition

If $u\in H^1$ then $\nabla u$ must be interpreted in the weak sense, this means that we call $\nabla u$ the distribution that satisfies the following
$$
\int\nabla u\cdot\boldsymbol{\varphi},dx=-\int u,\left(\nabla\cdot\boldsymbol{\varphi}\right),dx
$$
for every $\boldsymbol{\varphi}\in C^{\infty}_c.$
Now for the left integral to be well defined it is sufficient that both $\nabla u$ and $\boldsymbol{\phi}$ are in $L^2$ and this is true, if $u\in H^1$.
